# Kernel density estimate takes values larger than 1

Tags: distributions, probability, estimation, python

I am using [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to estimate a pdf for some data. The problem is that the resulting pdf takes values larger than 1. As far as I understand, this should not happen. Am I mistaken? If so why?

Comment: (+1 to the possible duplicate) Just to convey this quickly: Probability is defined as an area under a curve. A probability associated with the value of a PDF at a single point is multiplied by 0 (ie. the width of a line) so if anything the probability itself is 0. The linked thread gives excellent further elaboration on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are mistaken. The CDF should not be greater than 1, but the PDF may be. Think, for example, of the PDF of a Gaussian random variable with mean zero and standard deviation $\sigma$:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$$
if you make $\sigma$ very small, then for $x = 0$, the PDF is arbitrarily large!

Comment: Another possible source of confusion is that the pdf of a _discrete_ random variable (also called pmf - probability mass function) indeed cannot exceed 1.

Comment: @Aniko: This is indeed a source of confusion. I think I understand now.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4220/919 .